# ImportError: /usr/lib64/libcairo.so.2: undefined symbol: pixman_region32_rectangles

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python 2.7.8 (default, Nov 28 2016, 12:34:20) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> import rrdtool
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: /usr/lib64/libcairo.so.2: undefined symbol: pixman_region32_rectangles

[image]

Comment: Don't post text as picture

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.pixman.org/ , `pixman` is a library used by `cairo`, and `pixman_region32_rectangles` must be a symbol in it.

So, the error means that the versions of `cairo` and `pixman` on your system are incompatible. You need to update either of them to correspond to the other (or just both to the latest version).